# GWT app - deploying on Tomcat or any other servlet container

Tags: java, tomcat, gwt, servlets, jakarta-ee

Is there a plugin for Eclipse GWT or any other method to automatically deploy and run GWT app on Tomcat (or any other Serlvet container)? For the moment the only method I know is copying the compiled classes into WEB-INF directory but this is an arduous work. Additionally you have to configure Apache Tomcat manually. I'd like to have something like in Eclipse Dynamic Web Project where you can run your servlets directly by spawning tomcat process.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write an Ant task to deploy and run your GWT app. It could copy the files and then tell your servlet container to reload the latest files.

Comment: here's a sample ant script for the same: http://blog.elitecoderz.net/gwt-and-tomcat-create-war-using-eclipse-to-deploy-war-on-tomcat/2009/12/

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for: "[How do I use my own server in hosted mode instead of GWT's built-in Jetty instance?](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/FAQ_DebuggingAndCompiling.html#How_do_I_use_my_own_server_in_hosted_mode_instead_of_GWT%27s)"?
PS: You only need to copy the contents of the war folder **once**.
PPS: I'm assuming here you want to be able to easily deploy your app to Tomcat during development, since you are bringing up spawning Tomcat from Eclipse - meaning it's not a production server.