# Deploying GWT in tomcat

Tags: java, gwt, tomcat, webserver

i am new to gwt and i am very much satisfied for my needs but my problem is how can i deploy and run it in my tomcat webserver and i tried googleing but cant get any success in that can any one explain how to deploy it with some samples ......

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208181/gwt-app-deploying-on-tomcat-or-any-other-servlet-container

Answer (score 4):

Read this article: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideDeploying.html

The webaps directory can be found directly under your tomcat home.

Answer (score 3):

I figured I wanted to put something on here because I kept digging in the wrong direction.  Everyone talks about how to copy this here copy that there.  The solution for me was extremely simple, and not nearly as complicated as these pages try to make them out to be.

If you are using Eclipse with GWT 2.4:
Right click on the project, select Google -> GWT Compile
Afterwards zip the contents of the war directory (rename to .war) and deploy.  Works great for Tomcat 6, no issues so far.

Answer (score 0):

I use this plugin to generate JAR file: https://code.google.com/p/gwt-project-export-wizard/.