# How to deploy Gwt RPC servlet on tomcat server?

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

I have apache-tomcat-7.0.16 and jdk1.6.0.25 on my window xp server. I install eclipse and copy the programer of stockwatcher from google site. I compile the program and run under eclipse development mode it is running fine.  The eclipse create the war folder i copy this war folder under apache-tomcat-7.0.16/webapps.. then i check my tomcat server by enter http://localhost:8080: it is working and run example of servlet of tomcat as well. Then i enter the **http://localhost:8080/war/stockwatcher.html.** It give some java error. Then is move and copy again now give the error page not found.

Content of the war folder is 
images
stockwatcher
web-inf
stockwatcher.css
stockwatcher.html

i think i copy the file on wrong location or i have to configure the tomcat

Answer (score 0):

What is this java error you speak of?
Are you sure GWT libs are located inside WEB-INF/lib folder? Those are required for the GWT-RPC mechanism to operate.

Please visit the following sites for reference:

http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Web-Toolkit/browse_thread/thread/3408c38464c57d4a?pli=1

[GWT app - deploying on Tomcat or any other servlet container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208181/gwt-app-deploying-on-tomcat-or-any-other-servlet-container)

Comment: it is working. i made the upper and lowercase name error. In html  src="Stockwatcher/stockwatcher.nocache.js i changed it to  src="stockwatcher/Stockwatcher.nocache.js. Same this capital letter mistake in web,xml file. I corrent the mistake and recompile the in eclipse and copy the war file to webapps and then in url i use http://localhost:8080/war.. it is show my page. If i want the url like this what should i do on tomcat "http://localhost" or "http://www.example.com" and run my application.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. What you have on mind is what is necessary to avoid writing the '8080' port number in the URL?

Answer (score 0):

do not use that war folder to deploy a gwt application to tomcat. it will not work. the procedure is:
1) gwt Compile the project first.
2) create a webbuilder.xml file and put the code under in it.

```
<project name="ExceptionReport" basedir="." default="default">

    <target name="default" depends="buildwar,deploy"></target>

    <target name="buildwar">
        <war basedir="war" destfile="
                    ExceptionReport.war" webxml="war/WEB-INF/web.xml">
        <exclude name="WEB-INF/**" />
        <webinf dir="war/WEB-INF/">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </webinf>
       </war>
     </target>

     <target name="deploy">
    <copy file="ExceptionReport.war" todir="." />
      </target>

</project>
```

ExceptionReportis my project name.

3) export the src folder as JAR file and save it in war>webinf>lib.
4) right click on web builder file and choose ant build option. it will generate a war file in your project.
5) put that war file on tomcat. and restart yout tomcat.